# Error while retrieving Parse data into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

```
var titles = [String]()
var descriptions = [String]()

 func retrieveData () {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Main")

        // get the actual data
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil || object == nil {

                println("Error retrieving data")

            } else {

                self.titles.append(object["Labels"] as! String) // ERROR!
                self.descriptions.append(object["desc1"] as! String) // ERROR!

            }

        }
    }
```

I have 2 arrays and I want to retrieve data from Parse and add it to those arrays, but I get this error:

```
 Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: this is what I get when I `println(object)` :

```
Optional(<Main: 0x7fc24b84e410, objectId: jy7LrEOMk0, localId: (null)> {
    Labels = labels;   
    desc1 = desc1;
    desc2 = desc2;
    desc3 = desc3;
    desc4 = desc4;
    desc5 = desc5;
})
Message from debugger: got unexpected response to k packet: OK
```

Comment: How did you declare the titles and descriptions array?

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours trying & searching, this is the correct answer:

```
self.titles.append(object?.objectForKey("Labels") as! String)
self.descriptions.append(object?.objectForKey("desc1") as! String)
```

The answer is so simple, but somehow the Parse.com docs don't have a single sample of it. Anyway I hope that helps anyone else who may get stuck at the same problem.